# how to insert whole data frame to oracle table with duplicate records in the data frame

Tags: r, rodbc

Every day I pul data from an external site and use RODBC to upload the data to the oracle table. It seems straight forward but somethimes the data that I am pulling from the external site may be duplicate (meaning there may be some rows in the data that may already exist in the oracle table).

I am currently doing this to load the data:

```
insert<-function(x){
tryCatch({
    x<-x[complete.cases(x),]
    x<-unique(x)
    x[, 3:5] <- sapply(x[, 3:5], as.character)
    x[, 3:5] <- sapply(x[, 3:5], as.numeric)
    ch=odbcConnect("<id>",pwd = "<passwd>")
    sqlSave(ch,x, tablename="<tablename>", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)
    print("insert of dat is successfull!!!!")
      },error = function(e) {
      print("insert failed!!!!")
      print(odbcGetErrMsg(ch))
    })
  odbcClose(ch) 
}
```

I have tested this and it shows that if there is a duplicate entry in my data frame to be inserted into the oracle table, the whole sqlSave fails.

If the whole sqlSave command fails, I can try to insert one line at a time, but this takes forewever to complete. The script never catches up.

I was curious to see is there an option to sqlSave or anything to just ignore the duplicate records and inserts everthing else with sqlSave. Any insight is greatly appreciate.

Comment: Is there a single primary key field (that exists in both the db and the data you're going to insert) that would indicate duplicate rows?

Comment: @joran, yes. the data frame and the table headers are the same. if I try to insert a data frame to the table and if the table has one record values are the same as one of the rows in the data frame, the whole sqlSave fails on the data frame.

Comment: So maybe do a SELECT first looking for instances of the key values you have in the data frame you're about to insert. Then remove rows with those key values.

Comment: @joran, I think I know what to do. I was hoping to find something that would handle this. Before I make the insert, I will get the last value from the db, subset my data frame given the last value, then insert it.